# In a pandas dataframe, replace a single row with multiple rows, based on splitting one column in the single row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
key     term        notes   Source
156349471   Aasdasd     Bleen   20623750
213740505   dfgdfgdfg   Blox    33052911
171645239   rtertertert sdffd   15805072|24361871|28885000
156134219   cvdv        dsfsdf  20305092|21259293|21905055|23136149
205936689   ddfg        dfsewr  34480604
205947819   xvcbfghf    svdst   34480604
213902333   jfghd       xcvsd   35020164
156133836   cvbcvb      xcvsfg  21907755|30098279
156349486   cvbcvb      xcv 24880025
156134727   dfgdfgdfg   sdfgdfs 24001450
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a dataframe from this, where each row that has multiple entries in the Source column, which is delimited by "|" is turned into multiple rows, with the rest of the row untouched. Thus:

`171645239  rtertertert sdffd   15805072|24361871|28885000`

would become:

```
171645239   rtertertert sdffd   15805072
171645239   rtertertert sdffd   24361871
171645239   rtertertert sdffd   28885000
```

For the whole example above, therefore, the ten rows, would become 16.

This is the code I tried:

```
new_data = []
for _, row in master_df.iterrows():
    for src in row['Source'].split('|'):
        new_data.append([row['key', 'term', 'notes', 'Source'], src])
        new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['key', 'term', 'notes', 'Source', 'src'])

print(new_df)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
File "notations.py", line 70, in <module>
    new_data.append([row['key', 'term', 'notes', 'Source'], src])
                     ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "XX\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1072, in __getitem__
    return self._get_with(key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "XX\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1082, in _get_with
    return self._get_values_tuple(key)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "XX\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 1126, in _get_values_tuple
    raise KeyError("key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex")
KeyError: 'key of type tuple not found and not a MultiIndex'
```

This code works:

```
import pandas as pd

diddly = {
    'A': ['gone1', 'gone2'],
    'B': ['PMID1|PMID2', 'PMID3|PMID4']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(diddly)

print(diddly)

new_data = []
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    for pmid in row['B'].split('|'):
        new_data.append([row['A'], pmid])
        new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['Gone', 'PMID'])

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
    Gone   PMID
0  gone1  PMID1
1  gone1  PMID2
2  gone2  PMID3
3  gone2  PMID4
```

so I'm wondering if it's the fact that my dataframe has more than two columns in the error case, but I'm not an expert.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

use following code

```
df.assign(Source=df['Source'].str.split('|')).explode('Source')
```

output:

```
    key         term        notes   Source
0   156349471   Aasdasd     Bleen   20623750
1   213740505   dfgdfgdfg   Blox    33052911
2   171645239   rtertertert sdffd   15805072
2   171645239   rtertertert sdffd   24361871
2   171645239   rtertertert sdffd   28885000
3   156134219   cvdv        dsfsdf  20305092
3   156134219   cvdv        dsfsdf  21259293
3   156134219   cvdv        dsfsdf  21905055
3   156134219   cvdv        dsfsdf  23136149
4   205936689   ddfg        dfsewr  34480604
5   205947819   xvcbfghf    svdst   34480604
6   213902333   jfghd       xcvsd   35020164
7   156133836   cvbcvb      xcvsfg  21907755
7   156133836   cvbcvb      xcvsfg  30098279
8   156349486   cvbcvb      xcv     24880025
9   156134727   dfgdfgdfg   sdfgdfs 24001450
```

If you want to reassign the index, you can use `reset_index(drop=True)` on the above results.

---

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'key': [156349471, 213740505, 171645239, 156134219, 205936689, 205947819, 213902333, 156133836, 156349486, 156134727], 
        'term': ['Aasdasd', 'dfgdfgdfg', 'rtertertert', 'cvdv', 'ddfg', 'xvcbfghf', 'jfghd', 'cvbcvb', 'cvbcvb', 'dfgdfgdfg'], 
        'notes': ['Bleen', 'Blox', 'sdffd', 'dsfsdf', 'dfsewr', 'svdst', 'xcvsd', 'xcvsfg', 'xcv', 'sdfgdfs'], 
        'Source': ['20623750','33052911', '15805072|24361871|28885000', '20305092|21259293|21905055|23136149', '34480604', 
                   '34480604', '35020164', '21907755|30098279', '24880025', '24001450']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response!

That looks as though it does what I want with the data, but it looks as though the (index values) of the original rows get duped too. Is there a way to drop those numbers?

Comment: looks like he wants a `reset_index(drop=True)` too

Comment: Damn, you guys are quick! Where does that go in the line?

Comment: Actually you should use `explode('Source', ignore_index=True)`. Note that this is a very frequently asked question, there are many duplicates of it already.